# How do I figure out the exact time complexity of my code?

Tags: python, time

So I made some code for a USACO question, and the intended solution was O(n^2). I'm not really sure what that means but my question is what's the exact time complexity of the following code? Is my code too slow for the intended solution?

```
import random

list = []
generatednumbers = []

def generatek():
    k = 3
    return k

n = int(input("Enter the amount of diamonds Bessy has: (up to 1000) "))

if n > 1000:
    exit("Bozo follow instructions")

if len(list) == 0:
    z = 0
    total = 0
    k = generatek()
    while True:
        z += 1
        generatednumbers = random.randint(0,10000)
        list.append(generatednumbers)
        if z == n:
            break


k = generatek()

list.sort()

total=0
newtotal=0
for j in range(len(list)):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[j] + k >= list[i] and list[j] <= list[i]:
            total+=1
    if j==0 or total > newtotal:
        newtotal = total
    total=0       

print(list)
print(f"k was {k}")
print(f"highest amount of diamonds bessy can hold is {newtotal}")
```

Edit: so from what the comments are telling me this is O(N^2), but the thing is the solution is just that and no additonal i guess time chunks. If my code has say O(n^2 + O(1)) then technically the solution won't work. I'm also curious how I can make the code O(n) if possible.

Comment: O(n^2) means program runtime scales quadratically with size of input. If you pass twice as much data, it will on average take 4 times as much time.

Comment: Since you have `for` loop nested in another `for` loop, there is a big chance that your code has O(n^2) time complexity. If you want exact time complexity of your code (it certainly won't be less than n^2), that might be a little complex. I would suggest that you look into time complexity (for example, here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-time-complexity-simple-examples/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the time complexity of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: In your case your code's time complexity is actually O(1), because your `list` variable is actually predetermined (`list = [1,2,4,6,1]`) and you actually skip taking any input from the users `if len(list) == 0:`

Comment: @MilosStojanovic, why did you say big chance and not just is? Are there scanarios where a for loop nested in a for loop isnt O(n^2)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry I should've clarified, the list is meant to be randomly generated. I forgot i left numbers in the list because that was USACO's sample input.

Comment: @limaosprey yes, you may have nested for loops that are not O(n^2). For example, let's say you want to find a pair of matching elements. You find one, then in inner loop find its match and break the outer loop. This is O(n) even though you have 2 loops.

Comment: Note: There's no such thing as `O(n^2 + O(1))` For time complexity only the biggest term is considered. So although while calculating something might look like `O(n^2 + nlogn)` that would only be considered as `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @matszwecja Let’s say I did something similar to that and I run through first the 1st elemtn of the list. I then check all items in the list if they match that and if they don’t, I move to the 2nd elemtn and 3rd, etc. Also if there’s a match I exit the loop. Would that be O(n) like you described?

Comment: No, let's say none of them matches - you have to check n-element list n times, so your pessimistic scenario is O(n^2)

Comment: So how was your solution earlier O(n)? You still need to check the first list for a match and if it fails you still move on to the next index right?

Comment: The scenario @matszwecja described is basically code that could have been two sequential loops written as nested loops. Which boils down to `O(2n)` since the 2 is not significant it is basically `O(n)`.